# What is the maximum intensity with which an earthquake can struck Chitral city in Northern Pakistan?

Tags: plate-tectonics, earthquakes, natural-disasters, transform-fault

I am working on a disaster response logistics case study in which I am using Mi-17 helicopters for transportation of relief to the affected areas in main Chitral city.

In this regard, I want to determine the maximum earthquake intensity which can be realized in Chitral City in northern Pakistan?

I have searched various databases and on various platforms such as Google Scholar, Science Direct, Scopus etc., but cannot find any information regarding this..

Comment: You can look at earthquake catalogs, for example the one from USGS: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/search/ You make a query with your area of interest and the longest time span available (some catalogs go back more than a century ago now) and look at the results. It will give you an idea of the largest events during that period and also of their frequency. Of course you'll probably miss the largest magnitude quakes, which occur at a very low frequency thus may not be yet present in those records. But from a civil protection perspective you want to focus on the most likely scenarios.

Comment: That a good resource but I am in search of a publication which may be analytically analyzing all the faults for their individual potential for generating an earthquake which will be particularly devastating for Chitralies.